# How to read PDF form controls for password protected file in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, itext, openxml

How to read PDF form controls from a file which is password protected for which Owner's password (OP) is unknown. Is it possible set the security level to 'no security' without the OP.

Comment: Just open it "unethically" ... PDF passwords are a bad joke.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/24464929/982149